# Simple onload doesn't work in JSFIddle

Tags: javascript, html

http://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/n5jb0159/

Simple document.body.onload event should trigger a javascript alert, but doesn't work but it works fine in my text editor -> browser.  I switched the libraries around to jQuery to None (pure JS), still nothing, can someone explain to me what's going on and why it doesn't work in fiddle but works fine in my text editor?

This works:

```
  <body>
    Why
    <script>
  document.body.onload = function(){
      alert("LOADED!");
  }
  </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: Use `window.onload` and change the "onload" option on the left to "No wrap". http://jsfiddle.net/18rd92p4/

Comment: Still didn't work for me, I tried no wrap in head and body both and changed document.body to window.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your first problem:

[image: Onload]

You have configured JSFiddle to run your JS when the `load` event fires.

Consequently, when the `load` event fires, you bind another `load` event handler.

Your new `load` event handler is never called because the `load` event has already fired.

Change the menu option to one of the "No Wrap" approaches.

---

Your second problem:

The `load` event fires on the `window` object, not the `body` element.

You need to assign the property to the right place.

```
onload = function(){
  alert("LOADED!");
}
```

Such: https://jsfiddle.net/n5jb0159/5/

Comment: This is so bizarre, it works for me when I use another browser but it doesn't work for me in Chrome, any clue why?  I'm using  Version 46.0.2471.2 dev-m (64-bit) if that matters at all for Chrome

Comment: Works fine for me in 44.0.2403.130 (64-bit)

Answer (score 3):

You code is good, just change your JSFiddle option from this:

```
onLoad
```

to this:

```
No wrap - in <body>
```

[Here is your updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n5jb0159/7/)

Comment: Thanks it works, any idea why it's not working for me in Chrome but works  on IE for me

Comment: @Snorlax It works in the latest stable version of Chrome. The version you're using is not stable, that's probably why it has this bug.

Comment: @PauloRobertoRosa You could always read [the documentation](https://docs.jsfiddle.net/panels-settings#javascript-panel)

Comment: Nope. the docs is outdaded, the load type option does not exists anymore. check it

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working http://jsfiddle.net/n5jb0159/8/

Just put the script inside the body.

```
<body>
    <script>document.body.onload = function(){alert("sdffds")}</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There also one notice against the behavior in `jQuery` for **onload event** behavior in JSFIddle.

Testing code in HTML DOM addEventListener() Method is as below:

```
window.addEventListener('load', initialProcess, false);
```

***LOAD TYPE: `onLoad`*** https://jsfiddle.net/chetabahana/a9dxv3fb/5/

> When Load type set to `onLoad`, the event **doesn't fires** an excecution

[image: onLoad option of jQuery 3.3.1 in JsFiddle]

***LOAD TYPE: `onDomready`*** https://jsfiddle.net/chetabahana/a9dxv3fb/6/

> When it was set `onDomready`, the event **fires and works fine**

[image]