# One JS function isn't working but the rest are fine in jsfiddle?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsfiddle

I read that an issue may be that my functions aren't global so I changed that but only my showSlides function isn't being applied/ isn't working? How do I fix this? Sorry if there's some obvious answer, I'm very new to webdev.

Note: I don't know whether currentSlide and plusSlides are working because showSlides isn't, but I'm assuming the issues are connected.

https://jsfiddle.net/8ynLwfcf/

```js
window.openModal = function openModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";
}
window.closeModal = function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

window.plusSlides = function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

window.currentSlide = function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex - 1].alt;
}
```

```css
 body {
   font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
   margin: 0;
 }
 
 * {
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 
 .row > .column {
   padding: 0 8px;
 }
 
 .row:after {
   content: "";
   display: table;
   clear: both;
 }
 
 .column {
   float: left;
   width: 25%;
 }
 /* The Modal (background) */
 
 .modal {
   display: none;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 1;
   padding-top: 100px;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
 }
 /* Modal Content */
 
 .modal-content {
   position: relative;
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
   margin: auto;
   padding: 0;
   width: 90%;
   max-width: 1200px;
 }
 /* The Close Button */
 
 .close {
   color: white;
   position: absolute;
   top: 10px;
   right: 25px;
   font-size: 35px;
   font-weight: bold;
 }
 
 .close:hover,
 .close:focus {
   color: #999;
   text-decoration: none;
   cursor: pointer;
 }
 
 .mySlides {
   display: none;
 }
 
 .cursor {
   cursor: pointer
 }
 /* Next & previous buttons */
 
 .prev,
 .next {
   cursor: pointer;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   width: auto;
   padding: 16px;
   margin-top: -50px;
   color: white;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 20px;
   transition: 0.6s ease;
   border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
   user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
 }
 /* Position the "next button" to the right */
 
 .next {
   right: 0;
   border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
 }
 /* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
 
 .prev:hover,
 .next:hover {
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
   text-decoration: none;
 }
 /* Number text (1/3 etc) */
 
 .numbertext {
   color: #f2f2f2;
   font-size: 12px;
   padding: 8px 12px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
 }
 
 img {
   margin-bottom: -4px;
 }
 
 t img.hover-shadow {
   transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
 }
 
 .hover-shadow:hover {
   transform: scale(1.1);
 }
 
 .modal-content {
   -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
   animation-name: zoom;
   animation-duration: 0.6s;
 }
 
 @-webkit-keyframes zoom {
   from {
     -webkit-transform: scale(0)
   }
   to {
     -webkit-transform: scale(1)
   }
 }
 
 @keyframes zoom {
   from {
     transform: scale(0)
   }
   to {
     transform: scale(1)
   }
 }
```

```html
<body>

  <h2 style="text-align:center">Modal Albums</h2>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://www.yosemitehikes.com/images/wallpaper/yosemitehikes.com-bridalveil-winter-1200x800.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
        <img src="https://www.yosemitehikes.com/images/wallpaper/yosemitehikes.com-bridalveil-winter-1200x800.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
        <img src="http://www.hardwallpapers.com/uploads/3527_Smudge-hdr.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
        <img src="https://assets.rockefellerfoundation.org/app/uploads/20151124121133/15659655525_e6cfc22b56_o-1200x800.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
        <img src="https://support.kickofflabs.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/800x1200.png" style="width:100%">
      </div>

      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: *"I only typed this because stackoverflow told me to"* - Please [edit] your question to remove that irrelevant code block, and instead include the relevant code directly in your question's body. Fiddles are a useful supplemental resource, but shouldn't be relied upon as the only source for the code you're asking about. Regarding the problem, have you checked your browser's console? (If you do you'll see a runtime error that should help you narrow down the problem.)

Comment: Try showing each block of code and explaining what is going on at each step this might help people give you an answer instead of 'debug my code'

Comment: browsers **developer** tools console (which should be your first point of debugging, even before stckoverflow) shows `TypeError: dots[(slideIndex - 1)] is undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Variable dots is empty because do not have any element with classname 'demo'. Even captionText is empty, you do not have any element with id 'caption'.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define the function on widow object.
change all the function definitions like

```
window.openModal = function openModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";
}
```

to

```
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";
}
```

you can change the way jsFiddle run the script by changing the settings.

Link to similar answer:  [Simple onload doesn't work in JSFIddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31946528/simple-onload-doesnt-work-in-jsfiddle)

[image]

Here is the fixed jsFiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/8ynLwfcf/9/

You need to fix the missing variable `dot` as there is no className called `demo`