# Remove <li> based on date on pageload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking for code that will dynamically remove events that have passed in my accordion. Here is the accordion:

```
 <div class="container3">

          <div class="accordion">
            <dl>
              <dt>
                <a href="#accordion1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordion1" class="accordion-title accordionTitle js-accordionTrigger">Travel Territory</a>
              </dt>
              <dd class="accordion-content accordionItem is-collapsed" id="accordion1" aria-hidden="true">
                <p><li>Test 1</li>
                <li>Test 2</li></p>
              </dd>
              <dt>
                <a href="#accordion2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordion2" class="accordion-title accordionTitle js-accordionTrigger">Catch me at these schools!</a>
              </dt>
              <dd class="accordion-content accordionItem is-collapsed" id="accordion2" aria-hidden="true">

                <p><ul id="myList">
                <li>03/24/2018 at Upper Darby High School 1</li>
                <li>03/24/2019 at Upper Darby High School 2</li>
                </ul>
                </p>
              </dd>
            </dl>
          </div>
        </div>
```

In the UL with the Id of Mylist, you will see dates. For testing purposes, I did two different years, but normally they would be within days of each other. I am looking to find some sort of code that will remove those

after the event has passed. I am looking to put about 15 events in that list, and do not want to have to go back and remove them after every event. Does anyone have any code that may work to remove the items depending on the date and on the page load?

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: Duplicate of your own previous question, [Code to Dynamically Remove List items depending on date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51002081/code-to-dynamically-remove-list-items-depending-on-date) // Please don’t create duplicates - resolve whatever issues you have with the answers you already got on the existing question, over there as well. Plus, this is not a site to just drop of your requirements in the first place - you are supposed to show what you have done so far to try and solve this on your own. Please go read [ask].

Comment: Voting to close it..

Answer (score 0):

Small snippet for your problem.

First we get all of the li's.

Then we get the dates via split. Important here. If the date changes place or format, it will brake. I will recomend adding the dia via a data attribute.

Then we compare the date of the li to today.

And if it meets your condition, we remove it.

```
$('#myList').children().each( function(){
  let liDate = new Date(this.innerHTML.split(' ')[0]);
  let today = new Date;
  if(today > liDate){
    $(this).remove();
  }
})
```

```js
$('#myList').children().each( function(){
  let liDate = new Date(this.innerHTML.split(' ')[0]);
  let today = new Date;
  if(today > liDate){
    $(this).remove();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container3">

          <div class="accordion">
            <dl>
              <dt>
                <a href="#accordion1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordion1" class="accordion-title accordionTitle js-accordionTrigger">Travel Territory</a>
              </dt>
              <dd class="accordion-content accordionItem is-collapsed" id="accordion1" aria-hidden="true">
                <p><li>Test 1</li>
                <li>Test 2</li></p>
              </dd>
              <dt>
                <a href="#accordion2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordion2" class="accordion-title accordionTitle js-accordionTrigger">Catch me at these schools!</a>
              </dt>
              <dd class="accordion-content accordionItem is-collapsed" id="accordion2" aria-hidden="true">

                <p><ul id="myList">
                <li>03/24/2018 at Upper Darby High School 1</li>
                <li>03/24/2019 at Upper Darby High School 2</li>
                </ul>
                </p>
              </dd>
            </dl>
          </div>
        </div>
```